# CrudRepositories - @Query process query parameters before executing

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

This is a Simple interface

```
public interface HPCrudRepository<T,ID extends Serializable>{

    @Query("<how to write query here")
    public List getThis(String somevalue);

}
```

in the above example, the parameter `someValue` cannot be passed directly to the query. I would have to do some preprocessing (say split by comma or pipe symbol).

How do I pre-process  the parameter variable

Comment: dont think this is possible. You have to write you implementation of your interface.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think there is a solution for your requirement. But if you dont want to create your own implementation class you can do your preprocessing stuff in your interface directly.

In Java 8 the `default` keyword was added which enable the functionality to wright logic inside an interface method.

So you can create a method for preprocessing which then calls the right Query-Method of your interface.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

    @Query("Select u from User u where u.name = :s")
    User findUserByName(@Param("s") String s);

    default User findUserByNamePreprocessing(String s) {
        //do you reprocessing stuff here..
        return this.findUserByName(s);
    }
}
```

And then you can decide if you need to call the query directly or use the preprocessing one instead.

```
 User user = repo.findUserByNamePreprocessing("Username");
```

I think its a good and simple solution for small and simple preprocessing requirements. If it gets to complex, create an implementation class.

Comment: Looks neat but unfortunately, am working with 1.7 only.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the solution you are looking for but you can add custom [behaviour](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour) to your spring data repository.

First you create a separate interface

```
public interface HPCrudRepositoryCustom {
    public void customMethod();
}
```

Then provide the implementation that does the processing.

```
public class HPCrudRepositoryImpl implements HPCrudRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    HPCrudRepository hpCrudRepository; 

    public void customMethod(String somevalue) {
       // process someValue
       ...
       hpCrudRepository.getThis(processedOutcome);
    }
}
```

Also you can check some examples [example1](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-eight-adding-functionality-to-a-repository/), [example2](https://egkatzioura.wordpress.com/2016/06/03/add-custom-functionality-to-a-spring-data-repository/)

Comment: Why should I autowire hpCrudrepository

Comment: Just for example purposes. You can either autowire the entity manager and use the jpa api or you crud bean and use the default actions. The example was edited.